# UIKeyboard get resign on UIAlertView button index click

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uialertview

I create custom `UIAlertView` and dismiss it on its own custom `button`, but its also resigning the keyboard from `UIWebView` load with editable div(I am writing something on it). How can I stop resigning the keyboard.

```
-(void)dismissAlertView
{    
     [alertForBuySmacks dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: set resignResponder to "NO" in that condition if you can fire.

Comment: where i will resign Responder to NO;

Comment: y  cant you use 
[alertForBuySmacks removefromsuperview]; or else we can delegate method like textfiled resign firstresponder

Comment: because it donot remove the alert completely, if i use [alertForBuySmacks removefromsuperview]; the black shadow behind alert remain there.

Comment: then remove alertview from superview

Comment: i can't due to above reason, alert is not fully removed from super view.Black shadow of alert still remain there although blue view of alert gets removed